# Support for the experimental syntax 'decorators-legacy' isn't currently enabled How To Enable In Create React App?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, mobx, mobx-state-tree

I am trying to get up and running with react create app and  mobx state tree. I keep getting

```
Support for the experimental syntax 'decorators-legacy' isn't currently enabled (4:1):
```

I never used react create app so I am not sure how to enable, I tried making a .babelrc file but that did not help

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
    "plugins": [
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }]
    ]
}


import React, { Component } from "react";
import { observer, inject } from "mobx-react";

@inject("domainStores")
@observer
export default class MainComponent extends Component {
  async componentDidMount() {}

  render() {
    return <div className="main-container">
            helllo

    </div>;
  }
}
```

I am also open to suggestions if things have changed, I have not used the newest version of Mobx State tree so many there is a better way of doing this now?

Comment: Did you eject? I don't think CRA lets you override Babel config.

Comment: How do I eject? I only know the babel way that I used when I was using web pack.

Comment: Look in the package file, CRA sets up a script for it.

Comment: I am not sure what I should be looking for in package.json

Comment: Literally "eject": https://github.com/textbook/rps-e2e/blob/a63645c25c0b6a89200c919d91ae9086e1eb100e/package.json#L24

Comment: ok, I see it. am I to type on npm eject? As it is not liking that.

Comment: I believe when NPM is "not liking that" it makes suggestions about [`run[-script]`](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/available-scripts/#npm-run-eject), no? See https://create-react-app.dev/docs/available-scripts/

Comment: there are ways to extend cra configurations (one given below) without ejecting. after ejecting you will not be able revert this operation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

CRA does not allow you to extend your own configuration, so, in order to extend cra configuration, you will have to use `customize-cra` with `react-app-rewired`.

So, follow the steps below:

1. Install `customize-cra`, `react-app-rewired` and `@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators` using npm or yarn
2. add `config-overrides.js` at root level of your project and paste the code given below:

```
const {override, addDecoratorsLegacy } = require('customize-cra');
module.exports = override(addDecoratorsLegacy());
```

3. Update package.json scripts to the below ones:

```
"start": "react-app-rewired start",
"build": "react-app-rewired build"
```

P.S: if you want to use babel configuration then your `config-overrides.js` should be like:

```
const {override, addDecoratorsLegacy, useBabelRc } = require('customize-cra');
module.exports = override(addDecoratorsLegacy(), useBabelRc());
```

useBabelRc will load config from your root of project automatically.

Comment: Ok, I went with option 1 for now but I am getting:   Parsing error: Using the export keyword between a decorator and a class is not allowed. Please use `export @dec class` instead.

Comment: change your implementation of your class like this:
`class MainComponent extends Component {`
and move export to the end
`export default MainComponent`

Comment: Yep, that is what I ended up doing. I maybe have to start a new question as now I am getting an injection error.

Answer (score 0):

If you only using MST without regular MobX stuff and only need `inject` and `observer` then you can use regular function syntax, it looks not that great, but does not require any setup:

```
export const WrappedComponent = inject("domainStores")(observer(Component)
// Or use export default here if you prefer
```

If you are using other features of MobX then in MobX 6 there is a new thing that will probably allow you to drop decorators (like `computed`, `action` and etc) altogether, `makeAutoObservable`:

```
import { makeAutoObservable } from "mobx"

class Store {
  // Don't need decorators now
  string = 'Test String';

  setString = (string) => {
    this.string = string;
  };

  constructor() {
    // Just call it here
    makeAutoObservable (this);
  }
}
```

With that you don't even need decorator syntax to be enabled.

More info here
https://mobx.js.org/migrating-from-4-or-5.html
and
https://mobx.js.org/react-integration.html

Comment: Does this flow to the Mobx State Tree as well?

Comment: Well, yes, its just different syntax for decorators.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the old decorators proposal, you can use `observer` as a function on your components instead of as a decorator.

We can also use React's own context instead of `inject`, as [the documentation states](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react#provider-and-inject):

> *Note: usually there is no need anymore to use `Provider` / `inject` in new code bases; most of its features are now covered by
> `React.createContext`.*

This way we can use Create React App as is.

**Example**

```js
import React from "react";
import { observer } from "mobx-react";
import { types } from "mobx-state-tree";

const StoresContext = React.createContext("store");

// custom hook that we can use in function components to get
// the injected store(s)
function useStore() {
  return React.useContext(StoresContext);
}

const StoreModel = types.model({
  things: types.array(types.string)
});
const storeInstance = StoreModel.create({ things: ["foo", "bar"] });

// instead of using the @observer decorator, we can use observer as
// a function and give it a component as argument
const MainComponent = observer(() => {
  const store = useStore();
  return (
    <div>
      {store.things.map((thing) => (
        <div key={thing}>{thing}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
});

export default observer(function App() {
  return (
    <StoresContext.Provider value={storeInstance}>
      <MainComponent />
    </StoresContext.Provider>
  );
});
```

Comment: hmm, things change so fast, so the decorators are not the way they are going anymore? I thought they were a lot cleaner then this way.

Comment: @chobo2 Yes, I used to use the decorators all the time myself as well, but as it's a proposal that will not make its way into JavaScript anymore it is being less used. E.g. the [MobX documentation recommends not using them anymore](https://mobx.js.org/enabling-decorators.html#enabling-decorators-).